# Unable to run Magento site offline. DEV server redirects to live store

Tags: magento

I have a Magento site running on a live e-commerce server.

I downloaded the whole site for offline use in a development environment. I changed the Base URL values in the database and edited the local.xml file but my local development site is still referring to the online store.

How do I correct this?

Comment: Highly pertient to Magento programming, how are you going to develop if you can't run your own DEV server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The usual problem, changing your base urls and local.xml is only a minor part of the equation.
`Step 3` was missed on moving the website to the development server.

Moving stuff is actually pretty darn simple.

1. a. Tar the public_html directory on the old server

   b. Reinstall on the development system.
2. a. Disable caching in Magento on the old server, dump the database and then reenable the Magento cache.

   b. Create a mysql database, user and grant permissions on the development system. Load the database dump into the database on the development system.
3. **Do the one thing that most people ignore, go set your file permissions and ownership.**
4. Change your base URLs using either mysql command line or phpMyAdmin.
5. Go eliminate every subfolder in the var/ folder, Magento will recreate it.
6. Finally, go make changes to your local.xml file to change the database access credentials assigned to the new database and bring Magento up.

If you have complete ownership of the server, do the above steps with the Apache server down until you've loaded all the data and made the permissions and file corrections. This prevents accidentally starting Magento in an unprepared state which can cache Magento's configuration which is why you are having this problem.

If you do not have proper permissions on the var/ folder and subfolders, Magento will **write your Magento temporary and cache to the system temp** and you end up with **Mage's magically redirected Magento** which eternally points to the original website.

Also, if you copy local.xml to another file to save it, name it something like local.xml.sv0 otherwise if it ends in .xml, Magento autoload each .xml file in app/etc/ and try to merge it with the contents of your local.xml file.

**NOTE:** What happens when you don't properly set file/folder permissions before running Magento for the first time after a move.

[image]

[image]

Comment: An excellent answer. Ah, the joys of that temp issue, I remember a very frustrating few hours before I learned that one. Worth noting you can create a tarball that retains all the file and directory permissions.

Comment: Thank you so much. This resolved my problem but now I am facing a new one. My theme is lost and the page is scattered. Why is this so? and how do I fix this?