# Magento Core Config Data Cache

Tags: php, magento, caching, magento-1.7

I had some configuration data caching issues in my magento frontend that,

- I cannot get new shipping rates/get template path hints/ etc..
- `core_config_data` table get updated correctly and All backend data shown correcty.

I tried "Flush Magento Cache" button, cleaning `<DocumentRoot>/tmp` directory,  cleaning `var/cache` directory

(This issue is noticed 2 weeks before and I moved the site to new VPS a month before)

Any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check file/folder permissions, the non-flushable, ever magically unchangable core_config_cache is usually the result of having your var/ folder tree unwritable somewhere so it all gets written to the system tmp folder.

Since the backend button only flushes contents in var/cache/, it will never touch anything in /tmp/* and you end up with this mysterious trait where it will change in the admin but the site will not read the config. I just had it happen last week on an upgrade where the permissions got changed.

[Similar problem here with URLs that cannot be updated and screenshots of the system tmp cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14778426/unable-to-run-magento-site-offline-dev-server-redirects-to-live-store/14779624#14779624)

[One of several posts on setting permissions for Magento to run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9244596/what-permissions-are-needed-to-run-magento)

Comment: thanks... problem has sorted after setting permission **777** to **var** directory & all its sub directories.
will my website vulnerable because of these settings

Comment: There should be an .htaccess file in var/ which is installed by Magento. It denies all access to this folder through the web server. Magento uses these .htaccess files in specific locations to prevent outside interference with the Magento application files, media storage and other folders. If you have control over the web server, you can tighten up the permissions necessary by changing the server processes to run as the account user instead of as separate named server accounts like www-data.

Comment: I don't have a idea about how sever level user accounts works. Who defined them?. I can see through my ftp client software that there is a owner defined for each and every file in the server. how to set permission as you suggest