# Magento Core Config Data not inserted in all environments

Tags: magento

I added in my system.xml a new config data, and it is working well in my developer server. It is inserted in db Core Config Data. 
However, on production server, my config isnt in Core Config Data.

Of course I cleared cache, refresh everything several times. Nothing changes.

Is there a cache file somewhere for this config that I have to delete manually?

Edit : 
I saw this, [Magento Core Config Data Cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18529059/magento-core-config-data-cache) but I have not rights on all /var folder, so I will need to know the exact place of this cache

Comment: Do you get any error message ?

Comment: Nothing in logs as far as i see, but it is a production server, so logs are fastidious to parse